# SurveyMonkey API multiple choice with "other" option

Tags: surveymonkey

So I've been looking into the surveymonkey v3 [api documentation](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#formatting-question-types) for formatting questions types.  What I want to do is create a multiple choice question that has an "other" option, which if selected has a text field that a user can fill in to be more specific. Is there a way to accomplish this with the api?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that when creating/updating a question.

Example:

```
POST /v3/surveys/<id>/pages/<id>/questions

{
  "family": "single_choice",
  "subtype": "vertical",
  "answers": {
    "other": [{
      "text": "Other (please specify)",
      "is_answer_choice": true,
      "num_lines": 1,
      "num_chars": 50
    }],
    "choices": [
      {
        "text": "Apples"
      },
      {
        "text": "Oranges"
      },
      {
        "text": "Bananas"
      }
    ]
  },
  "headings": [
    {
      "heading": "What is your favourite fruit?"
    }
  ]
}
```

This `is_answer_choice` field seems to not be accepted currently. That is a bug, you can [watch the docs](https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/public_api_docs) to potentially get notified on updates, or try it again later.

Edit: This method should work now, give it a try and let me know if it solves your problem!